# Unite Test for Windows 10 Universalapp

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

How do I run in debugger UT for Windows 10 universal app?

I was able to create UT app project, add reference to my main project and create UT class. However, I cannot debug or run this UT.

Comment: I can run unit test for uwp by following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh440545.aspx).

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you.